# Calling an action helper from a non-Controller class

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an action helper which I usually call in the controller like this:

```
public function myAction(){
   //some work
   $this->_helper->someHelper();
   //some other work
}
```

I've made changes to the code so that `myAction` now calls a method `myActionWork()` in a class and that method is what does the work.

```
public function myAction(){
   SomeClass::myActionWork();
}
```

The `myActionWork()` method is what does the work, so I put the 3 lines there. BUT, 1 of these lines is the call to the action helper `someHelper()`. So how can I still use the action helper from within a normal class? Can I do this or work around this?

```
class SomeClass {

    public static myActionWork()
    {
       //some work
       $this->_helper->someHelper();
       //some other work
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst this sounds like a bit of a mess, you could always just pass the helper as an argument, eg

```
class SomeClass {

    public static myActionWork(Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_SomeHelper $helper)
    {
       //some work
       $helper->someHelper();
       //some other work
    }
```

From your helper, call

```
SomeClass::myActionWork($this->getActionController()->getHelper('SomeHelper'));
```

### Update

An alternative method would be to statically pull the required helper out of the helper broker, eg

```
$someHelper = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('SomeHelper');
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to pass the action helper, if there's another way around it.

Comment: @sameold Why not? If you're going to use it, it kind of needs to be there. I have thought of another way though, will update my answer.